# Close keyboard in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on a web application which will be accessed from iOS `UIWebView`. When user touches an input text field, the `UIWebView` automatically opens the keyboard. Everything is fine up to this point.

Now when user taps anywhere on the page I want to dismiss the keyboard. What would be the method to do this.

I tried following code but that did not work for me -

```js
            $(document).on("tap", function (e) {
                document.activeElement.blur();
            });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am looking for a Javascript solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
document.foo.bar.myinput.blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you out.

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur()"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-Javascript option:

Start by adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIWebView` in your `ViewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissWebViewKeyboard)];
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    //the rest of your initialization code goes here
}
```

And then, add your `dismissWebViewKeyboard` method, which just ends editing on your `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)dismissWebViewKeyboard
{
    [self.webView endEditing:YES];
}
```

And that should do it!